# How to use Swashbuckle with Angular 2 .net Core 2 app

Tags: angular, .net-core, swashbuckle

I'm trying to set up swashbuckle on a .net core 2 angular project.

This project was generated using the dotnet new angular template from the cli.

I've added the proper things to the startup.cs class per the swashbuckle guide but angular2 is handling the /swagger route and redirecting back  to home because of the '**' route.

Any idea how to get swashbuckle working with the angular 2 dotnet project?

Comment: I sure wish people that down vote would say whats so bad about these questions

Comment: Cons because everybody's working out of the box for Angular 6 and Asp.net core 2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the fallback spa route from the configure method:, and creating a .MapWhen per this github issue:
https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/973

```
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            /*

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                */ 
        });

  app.MapWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/swagger"), builder =>
        {
            builder.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        });
```